# Two iphones - One comupter - One Apple account

Tags: windows-vista, iphone

This weekend I purchased a new iphone 3GS for my wife. I already have an original iphone.

I was wondering if I should set up different accounts for each phone or can I use just one account (my preference). We have purchased a good bit of music from Itunes over the years and I want to be able to put the music on both our phones. My current system is a windows vista machine.

Specifically if I use one account:

- How does itunes handle purchased applications for the iphone? Will I always have to purchase 2 copies now, even if I just want it for 1 phone?
- Will my purchased music be able to be played on both phones?
- Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do that I am just not seeing?

Now I have not tried anything yet, as I was researching the best way to do this before  I started plugging things in. I found [this](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1655495) discussion that was discouraging, but is somewhat old. And [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=359550) discussion that was more positive, but also old. So I was hoping some superusers may have some personal experience doing this and could share more current results and setups that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - How does itunes handle purchased applications for the iphone? Will I
>     always have to purchase 2 copies now,
>     even if I just want it for 1 phone?

The apps are separate per computer and/or per user login on the computer. When I go to download an app I've purchased, it prompts me to download again. I haven't tried with any apps I've paid for, which consists of one program :-).

> - Will my purchased music be able to be played on both phones?

Yes. You can authorize up to 5 computers to play the DRM-protected content from iTunes Music Store, and each of those computers can sync with iPhones/iPods. I don't know if there's a limit on the number of devices though.

> - Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do that I am just not
>     seeing?

If there is, I haven't found it, as I'm doing similar ;).

In addition to using both phones on a single Windows system, I connect my phone with a Macbook, all with the same Apple account. It works fine, other than Music library differences between the computers.

Comment: So you are using to separate windows logins, or one?

Comment: Separate logins, I tried with both and the phones sync fine, though because of library differences under our respective logins, it didnt' sync any music or anything. My apps were unaffected though.

Answer (score 1):

From the [iTunes Store Terms of Service](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html):

*10. Purchase or Rental of Apple Content

a. Products Requirements. You acknowledge that use of Products may require the use of other hardware and software products (e.g., the ability to make copies of Products on physical media and render performance of Products on authorized digital player devices), and that such hardware and software is your responsibility. Products may only be downloaded once; after being downloaded, they cannot be replaced if lost for any reason. Once a Product is purchased or rented (as applicable) and you receive the Product, it is your responsibility not to lose, destroy, or damage the Product, and Apple shall be without liability to you in the event of any loss, destruction, or damage.

b. Use of Products. You acknowledge that Products (other than the iTunes Plus Products) contain security technology that limits your usage of Products to the following applicable Usage Rules, and, whether or not Products are limited by security technology, you agree to use Products in compliance with the applicable Usage Rules.

Usage Rules

(i) Your use of the Products is conditioned upon your prior acceptance of the terms of this Agreement.

(ii) You shall be authorized to use the Products only for personal, noncommercial use.

(iii) You shall be authorized to use the Products on five Apple-authorized devices at any time, except in the case of Movie Rentals, as described below.

(iv) You shall be able to store Products from up to five different Accounts on certain devices, such as an iPod or iPhone, and Apple TV at a time; provided that each iPhone may sync ring tone Products with only a single Apple-authorized device at a time, and that syncing an iPhone with another Apple-authorized device will cause any ring tone Products stored on such iPhone to be erased and, if you so choose, to be replaced with any ring tone Products stored on such other Apple-authorized device. Additional restrictions apply to Movies Rentals, as described below.

Comment: Well by the usage rules it seems the apps I buy, should only need to be bought once and can be used on both phones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that using one iTunes account from a single computer does work with multiple iPhones. It's pretty handy, actually.

Comment: Does that allow you to share apps across the phones? So buy 1 app and then put it on both phones?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what does.